# How to be in safe and profitable situation while project management applying tactics on me?

Tags: management, united-states, project-management

I am working for an outsourcing company. I was working on a new project as my first onsite assignment in USA. The situation was tough over there. I was searching better opportunities in USA.

At that situation I have been contacted by manager of my previous project and shows interest to take into his project as on site lead. The reason is I have strong experience in that project. I feel that situation become easy for me if I goes to that project. I sent my consent to that manager and discussed the same with my current manager. My current manager didn't willing to release me initially. Same thing has been communicated to my ex-manager and I forgot that incident. But later due to the pressure from higher management current manager decided to release after finding replacement for me and same communicated to me.

Now my ex-project manager told me that there would be client interview in order to enter into that team even if I am ex-team member of that project. They would like to conduct mock-interviews with senior members of the team before they put across the client. So I have been interviewed by their current team members.

Mean while the day come and my current manager find my replacement and released me from his project. Now I went to my ex-project manager and asked about offer in that team. I have been told by my ex-manager that as I have been out of team I need to ramp up with updates in the project and framework that has been used for that project and also I need refresh all my project knowledge. Otherwise there are less chances that I clear the client interview. I agreed with that.

Now she told me to go to some time offshore gain knowledge, clear client interview and work some time at offshore (the total duration would be 6 months) so that client will see no reason to deny me and pressurized me to take the decision within 2 days. I believe that idea would be good for me and the project also as I am correct fit for that project.I have some offers at outside company at that point of time. But I believe that joining this project will put my onsite career safe as I am correct fit for this company and decided to sacrifice 6 months of my onsite career with out looking other opportunities for the other projects.

Then I have traveled back to offshore. Now I am at offshore. They make me sit idle in the name of preparing for client Interview. I am now reporting to offshore manager. Now the communication to that ex-manager should happen through offshore manager. When ever I ask about schedule for my client interview, they are scheduling one mock interview with one of the other team member and giving me some feedback. And asks me to work on that feedback by saying that when I over come the negatives specified in that feedback I will be placed across client for interview.

I don't understand what is going on. At this situation I already lost other opportunities based on this opportunity.

How can myself put safe and profitable situation with these kind of management tactics?

What was the mistakes I have done with this episode? And what are the lessons for me?

Comment: It is quite a story, and you feel that there are ethically questionable management tactics going on, but it is not clear what *you* think the tactics are.  Can you please elaborate what you think management is up to and why you think they are doing this to you?

Comment: @maple_shaft: The only reason I could able to see that they don't have potential person at Offshore to lead the team. And their team is not growing at Offshore which is necessary for their existence. But I am not clear why they are getting delayed to put across client interview. But nevertheless I would like to get out of this situation with out hurting my career opportunities and benefits.

Comment: That does sound like they could be trying to take advantage of you.  Do you still have an H1B that you can get back into the US?  Perhaps if you start phone interviews and don't tell anybody then a US company might be willing to sponsor your H1B.

Comment: **And asks me to work on that feedback by saying that when I over come the negatives specified in that feedback I will be placed across client for interview.**  - What are the negatives?  I think you should probably work on those so that you can get placed again.

Comment: @maple_shaft: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. How ever I am not sure Organizations in USA will consider my profile for their evaluation as it has practical difficulties in it. Any how I can consider this as my last move and alternate move.

Comment: @Chad: I am happy to improve. How ever I would like to protect my opportunities and as the interview getting delayed my stay at offshore also get delayed which is not desirable.

Comment: @Ramesh - There is a not trivial expense of bringing you back from the states.  So I suspect that the decision was not made lightly.  Having worked with other offshore companies the acceptable level of work and competence is rather low compared to native workers.  I would conclude that your performance was what lead them to take that step.  It probably had to do with your interactions with the client rather than your ability to perform the job.  Just a guess but it is based on what I have observed in the past.

Comment: Based on the title, I thought this was a question about using management tactics to get into a safe and profitable situation, instead of asking how to get into such a situation after questionable tactics by management.

Comment: @Chad: If it is the situation, how can I confirm with management and asks professionally to provide an opportunity where I can fit and will perform good. And how to approach other managers who put my profile for their clients and their projects with out damaging myself because of the past failures. Please suggest

Comment: @GreenMatt: Thanks for feedback. Changed the title :)

Comment: @Chad: Thanks for your interest to help me. How ever my basic objective intention is to put myself safe and profitable situation. Gaining management confidence is one of the option which I not yet decided to opt it. Hence I am reverting back title to original. When I decided to go with that option, I can take the community help :)

Comment: @Ramesh then I agree with the other close voters this quesiton is to localized to matter to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to realize that some part of your performance leading this kind of situation. You better review your performance and sniff around for clues. Here management is trying to play safe game and your benefits are getting affected.

The best and obvious solution is you have to improve your skills and negatives. Forgot about what others are giving, firstly write down what communication or other negatives which probably getting affecting your performance and work on improving it.

When come to current situation, you talk with your manager and asks for a help by giving honest suggestion or feedback. Ask question deliberately " So and so performance or so and so results are affecting this or those have any impact." If they clearly says yes. And asks for their suggestions how to proceed with the situation. And asks for any other project opportunity where your limitations can effect less on results. And clearly ask for backup plan if the current plan doesn't work. If current offshore manager unable to help ask him " Can I take the help of other managers or higher managers" and go for other managers to look for better opportunities.

And finally groom your resume and look for better opportunities where your strengths will be helpful. World is so big. Surely you will get one of the other opportunity which suits to you.

Comment: It sounds like management is giving you a chance to get straightened out before firing you completely.  How would your benefits be affected by that.

Answer (score 3):

In such a situation, I would engage in a conversation with the management and being open about what you have noticed. You should ask them for a clear time table of what will happen in the coming six months.

It is highly probable that nothing is going to come out of it and that you will be in the same situation as you are now in six months from now. You need to prepare for this eventuality.

You need to take advantage for this experience in the USA to polish your resume and land another job elsewhere. It is important that you look at what the market as to offer while giving a chance to your current employer to improve your situation.